# Add values to nested dictionaries inside nested lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list, which contains lists. This lists contain dictionaries and this dictionaries contain dictionaries themselves (List -> Lists -> dictionaries -> dictionaries).

The data looks like this (only a small fraction, I have not just 3 like here but 1500 of the "second level" lists which usually contain about 5-15 dictionaries, which contain (always) 14 dictionaries; also, the dictionaries inside the lists are not the same across lists like here):

```
nest = [[{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}}],
     [{ 'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}}],
     [{ 'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}}]]
```

I have a second list which has the same length as my list (3 in this example but 1500 in my data).

```
val = [100, 200, 300]
```

I want to add the values from this list (val) to the nested dictionaries. So the first value of the second list should appear in every subdictionary of the first list, the second value of the second list should appear in every subdictionary of the second list etc.

It basically should look like this in the end:

```
nest = [[{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 100},  
    'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 100},
    'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 100}},
  { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 100},  
    'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 100},
    'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 100}},
  { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 100},  
    'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 100},
    'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 100}}],
 [{ 'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 200},  
    'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 200},
    'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 200}},
  { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 200},  
    'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 200},
    'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 200}},
  { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 200},  
    'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 200},
    'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 200}}],
 [{ 'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 300},  
    'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 300},
    'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 300}},
  { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 300},  
    'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 300},
    'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 300}},
  { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3', 'id': 300},  
    'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3', 'id': 300},
    'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3', 'id': 300}}]]
```

I tried

```
for sublist in nest:
sublist.append(val)
```

but that obiously didn't work like I wanted.

How can I add the values from the second list to the nested dictionaries of the nested lists?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to write some code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: added question and previous attempt as requested

Comment: What's `val`? You still have to iterate over `sublist` to get to the `dict` you want to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution manipulates the 'nest' itself and should be very performant therefore and doesn't need more space as needed.

```py
nest = [[{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}}],
     [{ 'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}}],
     [{ 'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}},
      { 'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3:'A3'},  
        'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6:'B3'},
        'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9:'C3'}}]]

val = [100, 200, 300]

for i in range(0, len(nest)):
    for y in nest[i]:
        for value in y.values():
            value['id'] = val[i]

print(nest)
# Result:
[[
{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 100},
'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 100},
'Dict13': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 100, 7: 'C1'}},
{'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 100},
'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 100},
'Dict23': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 100, 7: 'C1'}},
{'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 100},
'Dict33': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 100, 7: 'C1'},
'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 100}}],
[{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 200},
'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 200},
'Dict13': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 200, 7: 'C1'}},
{'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 200},
'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 200},
'Dict23': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 200, 7: 'C1'}},
{'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 200},
'Dict33': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 200, 7: 'C1'},
'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 200}}],
[{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 300},
'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 300},
'Dict13': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 300, 7: 'C1'}},
{'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 300},
'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 300},
'Dict23': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 300, 7: 'C1'}},
{'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 300},
'Dict33': {8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 300, 7: 'C1'},
'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 300}}
]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
val = [100, 200, 300]
nest = [[{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}, {'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}, {'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}], [{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}, {'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}, {'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}], [{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}, {'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict23': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}, {'Dict31': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'Dict32': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3'}, 'Dict33': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}}]]
new_nest = [[{c:{**d, 'id':a} for c, d in i.items()} for i in b] for a, b in zip(val, nest)]
```

Output:

```
[[{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 100}, 
  'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 100}, 
  'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 100}}, 
  {'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 100}, 
  ...]
 [{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 200}, 
  'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 200}, 
  'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 200}}, 
  {'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 200}, 
   'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 200}, 
  ...]
 [{'Dict11': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 300}, 
   'Dict12': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 300}, 
   'Dict13': {7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3', 'id': 300}}, 
    {'Dict21': {1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3', 'id': 300}, 
   'Dict22': {4: 'B1', 5: 'B2', 6: 'B3', 'id': 300},
  ....}]]
```